# Is it possible to oauth from mobile website via iphone/android installed app?

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, oauth, mobile-website

Here's the scenario:

1. Visitor uses mobile browser to come to my website
2. Visitor clicks login with Facebook/Twitter
3. Website calls out (maybe using URL Scheme, etc.) to Facebook or Twitter's application on the mobile device
4. The application initiates the Oauth flow and ultimately returns credentials to the mobile browser.

I know you can, for instance, open links in facebook or twitter using URL schemes (e.g., twitter://t.co...) so I'm wondering if doing the same for an oauth flow is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What if... Before the oauth, there's a link for them to download your application?? That way they can oauth from a WebView within the application

Comment: Building an app, for app to app oauth is one way to go.  What I'd like to do is not have to build an app simply to get an oauth flow to work.  

Most users use twitter/facebook app on their mobile (instead of going to those sites in a mobile browser).  So I'd like to oauth them through their app which almost always has their credentials already saved, versus redirecting them to twitter.com/facebook.com in a mobile browser, which many times won't have their credentials (so they have to input them, and this causes mass drop off).

Answer (score -1):

Ok. So. Just google for the facebook android API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android
And there you go!

Comment: This is not what OP asked, and the docs doesn't answer the question. The problem here is mobile site to app oauth, not app to app oauth.